# How can I upgrade rpm on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, rpm

In my CentOS 7, the yum is malfunctioned. I want to reinstall it. However, my "rpm" version is too low to reinstall yum? How can I upgrade rpm on CentOS 7? Thanks.
NOTE: I logged in as a root. And all these are done on a cluster, not personal computer.
Here are what I have done and the message I received.

```
rpm -U rpm-apidocs-4.11.3-40.el7.noarch
package rpm-apidocs-4.11.3-40.el7.noarch is already installed # not surprised because I have upgraded it

rpm -Uvh yum-3.4.3-163.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpm >= 0:4.11.3-22 is needed by yum-3.4.3-163.el7.centos.noarch

rpm --prefix="/usr/bin/" -U rpm-apidocs-4.11.3-40.el7.noarch.rpm 
error: package rpm-apidocs is not relocatable
```

Is it possible for me to install all dependencies together, like one command can install all dependencies and the package? I sincerely appreciate your time.
    rpm -Uvh yum-3.4.3-163.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
    error: Failed dependencies:
        rpm >= 0:4.11.3-22 is needed by yum-3.4.3-163.el7.centos.noarch

---

```
rpm -U rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-libs-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-python-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64


rpm -U rpm-libs-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpm = 4.11.3-40.el7 is needed by rpm-libs-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64
    rpm-libs(x86-64) = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm-libs(x86-64) = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
```

================================================================================

```
rpm -qR rpm-4.11
package rpm-4.11 is not installed

rpm -i http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm
    file /bin/rpm from install of rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/bin/rpm2cpio from install of rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/bin/rpmdb from install of rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/bin/rpmkeys from install of rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt-4.11.3 from install of rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/share/man/man8/rpm.8.gz from install of rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64


rpm -iUvh http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-libs-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-python-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
    rpm = 4.11.3-21.el7 is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Do you have the `rpm2cpio` and `cpio` programs installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the last version of `rpm` from CentOS 7 and update it:

```
rpm -U rpm-version......
```

then download yum packages and update it on the same way

The package you need to update is `rpm` not `rpm-apidocs`. Here is one mirror of this package:
http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm

To get list of dependencies you can use command:

```
rpm -qR rpm-version....
```

and install them on this way:

```
rpm -i pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
```

You do not need to download them, `rpm` understand http protocol so you can install on this way:

```
rpm -i http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The update will be line like this one:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm \
http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-libs-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64.rpm \
http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-python-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64.rpm \
http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-devel-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64.rpm \
http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-build-4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your time and suggestion. I did it. It looks I installed it successfully when I use "rpm --version". However, when I run rpm to upgrade yum, I still got the low version message. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Leon, can you add in question the exact commands you run and exact error message(s) you get

Comment: thanks. Yes. I updated my questions. The commands and error messages were appended in the question. I sincerely appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @leon, you update wrong package, please check my edited answer

Comment: @Leon, if you are happy with my answer you can consider to upvote and/or accept it :)

Comment: How can I get all dependencies installed together. When I installed the one you shared with me, it showed dependencies needed. When I installed one of them, then some new dependencies are needed.

Comment: @leon, I edit my answer.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help. Unfortunately, following your suggestion, I got the error messages which were appended in the questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104069/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-leon).

Comment: You are so nice! Yes I got it. I sincerely appreciate your time and help.

Comment: You are welcome, @Leon :)